# linearLayout.addView(TextView) not working

Tags: java, android

```
private LinearLayout clmnView;
LinearLayout clmnView = new LinearLayout(getContext());
LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
int margin = DimensionsHelper.getMargins(getContext(), DimensionsHelper.DimensionType.BALL);
params.setMargins(0, margin, 0, margin);
clmnView.setLayoutParams(params);
clmnView.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
clmnView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

TextView historyTextView = new TextView(getContext());
historyTextView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
                     LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
             historyTextView.setText("this is history");
clmnView.addView(historyTextView);
```

No matter what I do ,the historyTextView is not display inside my clmnView.
Could you please help? Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you defined ID's in `onCreateView`?

Comment: in which layout you add clmnView?

Comment: @DipankarBaghel It is another LinearLayout.

myPlaysLin.addView(clmnView);

Comment: @Filip123go can you paste that code too?

Comment: It is a huge snippet of code :/ . And I do not think that the problem lies there. I add other things in clmnView and they are displayed correctly.And I do not get any errors. That is why this is driving me crazy. ex. When i do this:  clmnView.addView(imgV);
                        Glide.with(getContext()).load("imageUrl").into(imgV); It works fine

Answer (score 0):

Okay everything was working as it should. But I was displaying white text in white background. 
Changed the color of the text like this :

```
historyTextView.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#000000"));
```

and my text appeared.